# error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs only sometimes, user permission?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

Some users in my app get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:    at
> com.file.gt.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult
> (MainActivity.java:234)   at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions
> (Activity.java:5323)   at com.file.gt.MainActivity.onCreate
> (MainActivity.java:85)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate
> (Activity.java:8114)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate
> (Activity.java:8098)   at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
> (Instrumentation.java:1309)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
> (ActivityThread.java:3480)

It occurs only sometimes, with some users.

I have this in my app:

```
private final String [] permissions = {
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
};

        int requestCode = 200;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                    checkSelfPermission(permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
            }
        }
```

and this:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        recreate(); // 234
    }
    else {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_title));
        alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_text));
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong and what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: u know there is a tool called debugger. You can even put conditions in the debugger in modern IDEs like Intellij to only stop at a breakpoint if condition (like out of bounds) applies. You should seriously go and explore debugging, because that is an essential skill of a developer

Comment: @JAsgarov thanks, I will learn. But I know where the problem is, just don't know what is missing on my onRequestPermissionsResult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` it means you are accessing an array index outside the array size. Your stack trace says it happens in `onRequestPermissionsResult`, and the only array you access there is `grantResults`.

What can [sometimes happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770955/in-onrequestpermissionsresult-grantresults-on-some-device-return-empty-when-user) is that `grantResults` is empty in `onRequestPermissionsResult` if the user declines the permissions, so you should check its size before accessing its members

```java
if(grantResults.length == 2 &&
   grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
   grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    recreate();
}
else {
    // handle permissions not granted
}
```

Alternately, if you use the new [`registerForActivityResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551781/android-onrequestpermissionsresult-is-deprecated-are-there-any-alternatives) approach you can get around this entirely. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java) for more info, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475027/activityresultlauncher-with-requestmultiplepermissions-contract-doesnt-show-per) for an example use.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final String [] permissions = {
android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, 
android.Manifest.permission. READ_PHONE_STATE,
};
int requestCode = 200;

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
if (context != null && permissions != null) {
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;}
```

//user this code to check

```
if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
}else{
   recreate(); 
}
```